# AOSP build error make -jN

Tags: makefile, android-source, ninja

I'm trying to build AOSP with `make -jN` command but it ends with the next error:

```
Running kati to generate build-aosp_arm.ninja...
out/build-aosp_arm.ninja is missing, regenerating...
opendir failed: .DocumentRevisions-V100: Permission denied
make: *** [out/build-aosp_arm.ninja] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (1 seconds) ####
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to invoke build process with root permissions:

```
sudo make -jN
```